# nestjs swagger-ui doesn't show information from decorator apiSecurity

Tags: nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

Il wrote a nestjs controller whith decorator

```
@Controller('sample')
export class SampleController {
  @Get(`/sample}`)
  @ApiOperation({
    description: 'sample controller',
    summary: 'sample',
  })
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'sample list',
    type: String,
    isArray: true,
  })
  @ApiSecurity({ roles: ['read'] })
  async getSampleList(): Promise<string[]> {
    return ['sample1', 'sample2'];
  }
}
```

the file swagger-spec.yaml generated contains correct information according to decorator @ApiSecurity :

```
security:
        - *ref_14
        - roles:
            - read
```

but the swagger ui (http://127.0.0.1:3000/swagger/#/default/SampleController_getSampleList) doesn't refer to this information ???

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jO0x.png)

nest version : 8.2.5

@nestjs/swagger version : 5.2.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added a complete sample to expose my problem, hopping it will be more comprehensive.